Inside second Cubit, emits the first Cubit state which leads to a infinity loop
I have a StatelessWidget (A1) with a BlocProvider which creates the Cubit A. And the child of that BlocProvider is another StatelessWidget (A2) which is the BlocBuilder. For the Success state of the Cubit A, builder will call another StatelessWidget (B1) which is another BlocProvider that creates the Cubit B. For the Finish state of the Cubit B, it calls the last StatelessWidget (B2).
But just before, when Cubit B emits the Finish state, it calls an API call which creates a new Object call Contact. That cause the Cubit A to trigger the Success state again which starts the infinity loop of creating above mentioned StatelessWidgets and Cubits.
final class Success extends ContactState {
  Success(this.contact);

  final Contact contact;
}

What I need is NOT to trigger the Success state for the second time when a new Contact object creates. Or close the link between A2 BlocBuilder state and B1 StatelessWidget once B1 screen has created. Is there a way to do that?
Or do you have a better design to address this issue?
